# How can i "update" a banner in Android?

Tags: android, banner

I have an app where I have one banner in the top with News, when I want to put other news I need to open the code and change the resource .jpg and the Link. There is a way to change the banner and the Link (or at least the banner) without modifing the code? Idk maybe uploading it to a webpage or something like this.
thanks

Comment: What's stopping you from dynamically changing the imageView during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to upload a banner.jpg to a server that your app can access and dynamically load. This would prevent having to update your app every time you want to change the banner, and makes it cleaner (no excessive Google Play updates). To do actually load the image you can use this code:

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mybanner);
new Thread(new Runnable(){//create a new thread so we can do network operations
    @Override
    public void run() {//main thread function
        try {//attempt to do network stuff
            URL url =  new URL("http://your-hosting-site.com/banner.jpg");//create aURL object with the path to your banner
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//create the connection object from the url
            con.setReadTimeout(15000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();//connect to the server
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();//get the stream so we can read the image
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "MyBanner");//create a drawable from the image
            Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();//create a bitmap from the drawable
            final Drawable dS = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 192, 192, true));//scale it to whatever size you need
            con.disconnect();//disconnect now that we're done
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){//run UI update code on the main thread
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    image1.setImageDrawable(dS);//set the imageview to the banner we downloaded
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {//catch url error
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {//catch io error when downloading
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();//run the thread
```

Change "http://your-hosting-site.com/banner.jpg" (line 6) to wherever you uploaded the .jpg, R.id.mybanner (line 1) to the id of your ImageView, and "MyBanner" (line 14) to whatever you want to call the image.

You might want to save your banner to the phone and only check after X days/hours for an update to save data, but that is up to you.

Comment: @amerite1 , thanks for answering.. i am completely newbie and I dont understand, because everytime I upload the banner to, for example imageshack.com the Link changes, so i need change the code right? or I dont get the mean of dinamically :S

Comment: I would suggest getting a free Web hosting account so that you can upload your images and have a site about you showing off your apps. That way, you can upload files and the path will stay the same. I have personally used 000webhost with success, but you can look around at what's out there. Note that you can't use their service just for file hosting; you will need a site of some kind to adhere to their tos